# price filter problem in magento

Tags: magento

In magento sidebar basically how the price filter option is working, i went through all the templte and block files under my custom design.

I am getting this ranges by default.

```
   1. $0.00 - $10,000.00  (1027)
   2. $10,000.00 - $20,000.00 (3)
   3. $20,000.00 - $30,000.00 (1)
```

These limits are automatically taken but i want give my own ranges, but they are using only one template file called filter.phtml if i touch that then all other filter options are having problem. How can i customize this price filter as per my own set of ranges?

I need something like this

```
 #  $40.00 - $60.00  (155)
# $60.00 - $80.00 (150)
# $80.00 - $100.00 (153)
# $100.00 - $200.00 (248)
# $200.00 - $300.00 (100)
# $300.00 - $400.00 (43)
# $400.00 - $500.00 (20)
# $500.00 - $600.00 (6)
# $600.00 - $700.00 (6)
# $700.00 - $800.00 (2)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look in `filter.phtml`, you will see that it is using the block `Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_xxx` where *xxx* is the attribute type.  Which in turn leads you to the model: `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price`.

Inside `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Price.php`, you will see the method `getPriceRange()` which calculates the price breaks.

You can override that model by copying it into `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter` and adjusting that method so that it calculates the ranges per your requirements.

Good luck. 
JD

Comment: yes i have solved this one from this post. http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/65135/, Thanks

Comment: But how can we create another slider for another product attribute like product size. is it possible?

Comment: See this "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21981736/add-slider-search-for-size-attribute-in-navigation-search-like-price-slider-in-m"